# Can I use spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channel>.group when using RabbitMQ to obtain exactly-once delivery?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

so I was reading this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream) to configure RabbitMQ and SpringBoot.

At a certain point it is said:

> Most of the time, we need the message to be processed only once.
>   Spring Cloud Stream implements this behavior via consumer groups.

So I started looking for more information on [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#consumer-groups) it is written that:

> When doing so, different instances of an application are placed in a
>   competing consumer relationship, where only one of the instances is
>   expected to handle a given message.
>
> Spring Cloud Stream models this behavior through the concept of a
>   consumer group. (Spring Cloud Stream consumer groups are similar to
>   and inspired by Kafka consumer groups.)

So I setup [here](https://github.com/invasionofsmallcubes/spring-boot-poc) two nodes with Spring Boot Cloud Stream and RabbitMQ and using `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channel>.group`.

This to me still looks like at-least-once behavior. Am I wrong in assuming that? Should I still manage the possibility to process a message twice even using `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channel>.group`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's at least once. The connection might close before the ack is sent. Rare, but possible.